# Why does flex depends upon bison?

Tags: compiling

I would like to know why does [flex](http://flex.sourceforge.net/) depends upon [bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Yacc) as given in [download page](https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/flex) of flex?

Comment: I don't see the word `byacc` anywhere on that download page.

Comment: @Jos:Oh sorry I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't, really. `bison` is merely a *suggested* package.

```
$ apt-cache show flex
Package: flex
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Installed-Size: 468
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Manoj Srivastava <srivasta@debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Version: 2.5.35-10.1ubuntu2
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11), m4, libfl-dev (= 2.5.35-10.1ubuntu2), dpkg (>= 1.15.4) | install-info
Pre-Depends: debconf | debconf-2.0
Recommends: gcc | c-compiler
Suggests: bison, build-essential
Filename: pool/main/f/flex/flex_2.5.35-10.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
Size: 198826
MD5sum: 27cb81027d75db58240873ec3f8fd3ed
SHA1: 253c08edd934d7e3a85beca7c527c7598544dada
SHA256: 870bc45e20265ba718ee9872a04d2d95e0af414eeb3129a16c53f0229965df5f
Description-en: A fast lexical analyzer generator.
 Flex is a tool for generating scanners: programs which recognized lexical
 patterns in text. It reads the given input files for a description of a
 scanner to generate. The description is in the form of pairs of regular
 expressions and C code, called rules. Flex generates as output a C source
 file, lex.yy.c, which defines a routine yylex().  This file is compiled
 and linked with the -lfl library to produce an executable. When the
 executable is run, it analyzes its input for occurrences of the regular
 expressions. Whenever it finds one, it executes the corresponding C code.
Description-md5: 2e3fd254c37c87fd9abf35386a54cb30
Multi-Arch: foreign
Homepage: http://flex.sf.net/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
```

You can simply install `flex` using `sudo apt-get install flex`.

Comment: :Yeah you're right.Could you tell me then why the download page shows bison as "build-depends".

Comment: @justin, it means the build operation  of flex packages needs to bison (may be, needs it to process some file) , but it doesn't mean it needs it for runtime.